# Wordpress pictures and thumbnails not working

Tags: wordpress, image, permissions, thumbnails

I've been having a few problems with my Wordpress Installations on a couple of my website.

1. The first problem is that uploading pictures works but when if I add the image to a post for example, it adds it but shows a broken image thumbnail. When I try to access the image though it throws a 403 error. Tried changing the permissions of my uploads directory to 755. Didn't work though.

You can visit [this](http://photography.alcratech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/001.jpg) link to get an idea of what's happening.

2. No thumbnails are showing up on the admin panel. Normally, in the theme installation window, there's a thumbnail on every theme that shows what the theme looks like, in my installation there's nothing like that. It just show blank thumbnails.

I've uploaded an image showing the thumbnail error [here](http://postimg.org/image/4f99jkcnz/).

At first I thought something was wrong with my Wordpress Installation, but after reinstalling it a couple times, I can see that it's something else. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This only permission issue, use 666 for upload folder then images is working well. check this https://codex.wordpress.org/images/e/eb/podz_filezilla_13.gif

Comment: Changed the permissions in FileZilla, still have  the same problem

Comment: upload one more image and check this is working or not

Comment: Finally figured it out, seems like I had hotlink protection switched on and that was what was causing the problem. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score -1):

If permissions didn't fix it then try this:

1/ Double-check that your PHP configuration is up to date with the latest WordPress version. I made the mistake cause I was previously working on Magento 2 and forgot to switch from PHP 7.2 to 7.4.

2/ Try basic approach deactivate all plugins and see if one is clashing. Do the same with your them or try a native theme TwentyThirteen instead.

3/ Install "Regenerate All Thumbnails" go-to tools and force thumbnails regeneration for the entire library